# I cannot reproduce the results with kmeans in Orange

Tags: orange

I've tried to repeat the same results with the same flow, and I don't understand the results are different in each situation.

I describe the situation I have a file with 192 instances and 37 features, y select in all cases the same columns and preprocess by Median and StdDev. It computes the PCA with 7 principal components. The following step is to run the k-means algorithm (k is between 2 and 8) from this 'new' dataset. The scatter plot shows the results for k=5.

I attached different images with my flows. 
[Image1: original flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWswc.png)

The first one is the original flow (it is painted of yellow color), which I would like to repeat without the rest of the options (the second image).

[Image2: flows repeated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekluo.png)

However, when I tried to do it, I saw that the results are different (the third image) Of course the colors don't determine the differences, however the clusters are different. In addition the Slhouette Scores are different too for the different flows.
[Image3: results of the different flows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgpxJ.jpg)

K-means initializes with the kmean++ and I have the question if I can "control" this, or if the way to initialize k-means is always randomly. I saw in other programmes that there is an option called seed which is used to control that an experiment can be repeated but I didn't see this option here or something similar.

I wonder if it is possible to obtain always the same results with the same flow (using k-means).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue happens because no random seed is set in the k-means widget. So initialization is different each time you repeat an experiment and because of nature of your data, the method converges differently. Can you please report your issue to [Orange3 issue tracker](https://github.com/biolab/orange3/issues).

Comment: Ok, I will. Thanks Primoz for your answer.